# File I/O - Displaying contents of a file

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, system-calls, tcpserver

I was looking for some advice on a function for a simple TCP server.

The third `if` statement, is suppose to check if `token[1]` is a name to a file or a directory (which is working fine). My problem is, opening the file, displaying the contents of the file to the client and then closing the file. I tried using file I/O calls but, haven't a way to do so that work. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
void processClientRequest(int connSock) {

 int received, count = 0;
 char *token[] = { (char*)0, (char*)0 };
 char path[257], buffer[257];

 // read a message from the client
 if ((received = read(connSock, path, 256)) < 0) {
    perror("receive");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 path[received] = '\0';
 cerr << "received: " << path << endl;

 for(char *p = strtok(path, " "); p; p = strtok(NULL, " ")) //sets tokens
    token[count++] = p;

 if(strcmp(token[0], "GET") != 0) { //if the first "command" was not GET, exit
    strcat(buffer, "Must start with GET");
    write(connSock, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    exit(-1);
 }

 int rs;
 int fd, cnt;
 struct stat bufferS;
 rs = stat(token[1], &bufferS);

 if (S_ISREG(bufferS.st_mode)) { //input was a file
    fd = open(token[1], O_WRONLY); //open
    cnt = read(fd, buffer, 257); //read


    write(connSock, buffer, strlen(buffer));        
 }
// else, open directory and stuff (code for that has been omitted to save space)

cerr << "done with this client\n";
close(connSock);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to read from a file descriptor that is opened as write only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read on a file, if you open it for writing only:

```
fd = open(token[1], O_WRONLY); //open
```

You need to open it for reading, O_RDONLY in your case, if you do not want to write anything to it (else O_RDWR).

By the way - Your buffer sizes are odd (257), normally, one allocates buffers in powers of two (256).

UPDATE:

Be warned that read does not necessarily null-terminate the strings! Use cnt instead of strlen(buffer) for writing - but check it for being < 0 (error) and == 0 (end of file) before. You might want to do this in a loop, if your files can have arbitrary size (i. e. possibly larger than the buffer).

Comment: Thanks for that! Also fixed the sizes!

Comment: Sorry about that, had issues with computer.